# Image optimization is available only for sites that use Salesforce's CDN for Digital Experiences

Tags: deployment, experience-cloud

I'm deploying some changes to an existing Experience.  For the `Network` metadata, I get this error

```
Image optimization is available only for sites that use Salesforce's CDN for Digital Experiences
```

This error did not occur when deploying from `dev - > integration -> staging`; only from `staging -> PROD`

If I look at the XML in the source org (actually the source branch corresponding to Staging org), I see:

```
 <enableImageOptimizationCDN>true</enableImageOptimizationCDN>
```

How do I resolve this error in the deployment to PROD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metadata item  `<enableImageOptimizationCDN>true</enableImageOptimizationCDN>` was added in V56 of the MDAPI for metadata type [Network](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_network.htm?q=network).

Per the [CDN doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_cdn_overview.htm&type=5), Salesforce CDN is auto-enabled for orgs with enhanced domains enabled. Well, my dev, integration, and  staging orgs have been auto-enabled for **Enhanced Domains** as of Winter 23 but the PROD org is not yet on **Enhanced Domains**.

This means one has four choices:

1. [Setup SFDC CDN](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.community_builder_cdn.htm&type=5) in PROD
2. Do the deployment at V55 or earlier as the `enableImageOptimization` was added in V56
3. Coerce via PR the environment/promotion branches to change the setting to `false` and deploy again at V56. Once PROD is enabled for Enhanced Domains, then revert VCS branch(es) back to `<enableImageOptimizationCDN>true</enableImageOptimizationCDN>`. If done in the promotion branch, VCS can still represent what is in the org during the interim period. The `main` branch can be refreshed in v57 when Enhanced Domains take effect in all orgs (unless postponed via opt-out)
4. Don't deploy the `Network` metadata at all - this works for updates to existing Experiences where the delta in XML for `Network` between your source org and PROD org may be irrelevant